# Help with Grease Pencil - Why do my strokes flicker?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I was hoping somebody may be able to give me some advice on the Grease Pencil issue I'm having. I'm fairly new to 2D on Blender (some experience with 3D) so I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing or not. I've been playing with GP and made a few little tests although I keep having the same issue where some strokes will flicker as the camera moves. Below is an example where the back wall strokes and windows "flash" as the camera pans out;
https://youtu.be/mBKJF-pQGAo

I would say it looks like vertex fighting but in the example above my strokes are in one layer and fills in the layer below so I don't think this should be a problem?

I have tried animations on stable and unstable versions and all have this artifacting at certain stages.
Any help will be great.

Thanks
Matt